# How to select a json property using jq and regex?

Tags: json, regex, jq

I have a `json` file like this one below:

```
{
  "Resources": {
    "NodeLaunchConfig123456789": {
      ...
    }
  }
}
```

How can I select the property `NodeLaunchConfig123456789` using `jq` and a regex like `NodeLaunchConfig\w+`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution which uses [`with_entries`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#to_entries,from_entries,with_entries) and [`match`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#match(val),match(regex;flags)).

```
def condition:
  .key|match("NodeLaunchConfig[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")
;
{
  Resources: .Resources | with_entries(select(condition))
}
```

If you would rather not break out the condition into a separate function you can use

```
{
  Resources: .Resources | with_entries(select(.key|match("NodeLaunchConfig[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")))
}
```

Depending on your actual data this could be shorted a little with update assignment [`|=`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Update-assignment:|=) to just:

```
.Resources |= with_entries(select(.key|match("NodeLaunchConfig[a-zA-Z0-9_]+")))
```